# Coin graph is 4-colorable

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

How can we prove that a coin graph is 4-colorable???Also, can we find any example of an non-3-colorable coin graph.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92883/small-4-chromatic-coin-graphs for examples of non-3-colorable coin graphs. As to your first question, every coin graph is planar . . .

Comment: Also: The picture on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_graph is non-3-colorable... This page also clearly states that your question is equivalent to the four-color-problem. This does not show much effort on your side...

Comment: @JohannesHahn, your second point is not correct: coin graphs are circle packings where each circle is required to have radius 1. So, in particular, "every coin graph is four-colorable" is *not* equivalent to the four color theorem. In fact, the question I linked to says that "it's easy to show by induction" that every coin graph is four-colorable.

Comment: @NoahS That's not the definition of "coin graph" wikipedia uses. Is this some sort of standard terminology that is used in the wrong way? (I'm not a graph theorist and haven't heard of coin graphs at all before this question)

Comment: I was going by the definition in the linked question. (I'm not a graph theorist either :P) Seems there is ambiguity there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "coin graph" sometimes requires equal coins and sometimes allows non-equal coins. I am assuming the former meaning as indicated in the comments: equal coins.

[This paper](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/129193/files/coincikk.ps) says that the 4-colourability can be proved using a "simple induction".  I'll try: Consider the convex hull of the coin centres.  A coin whose centre is a vertex of the convex hull is adjacent to at most 3 other coins, so you can always colour it after you colour the others.

Finally, the example shown in Fig 1 of that paper is not 3-colourable.